# Igraph package R issue with layout_on_grid

Tags: r, plot, graph, igraph

I'm trying to plot a graph with layout_on_grid and receiving the message

> Warning message: In if (axes) { :   the condition has length > 1 and
>   only the first element will be used

It not only gives the warning, but don't apply the expected layout.

It does not seem to be an issue from the graph itself

```
library(igraph)

rG <- erdos.renyi.game(25,0.2)
plot(rG)
```

as we can see [image]

but with the layout, the warning.

```
plot(rG, layout_on_grid(rG, dim=2))
```

I have tested with directed and undirected edges and with edges with null or positive weights.

and the layout works here

```
el <- matrix(nc=3, byrow=TRUE,
             c(1,2,0, 1,3,2, 1,4,1, 2,3,0, 2,5,5, 2,6,2, 5,2,1, 3,4,1,
               3,7,1, 4,3,0, 4,7,2, 5,6,2, 5,8,8, 6,3,2, 6,7,1, 6,9,1,
               6,4,3, 8,6,1, 8,9,1, 7,10,4) )
g <- add_edges(make_empty_graph(10), t(el[,1:2]), weight=el[,3])
plot(g)

plot(g, layout=layout_on_grid(g, width = 4))
```

[image]

Any ideas I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Any example that throws the warning? Both examples work.

Comment: sorry :)  plot(rG, layout_on_grid(rG, dim=2))

Comment: `plot(rG, layout=layout_on_grid(rG, dim=2))`? The 2nd argument of `plot.igraph` is `axes` - so you were effectively giving it a matrix, where it wants a logical `TRUE`/`FALSE` value...

Comment: @lukeA thanks for pointing it out. What a lack of attention of mine. I must delete this dumb question. I just didn't set the parameter correctly.

Comment: It's not dumb and I would not delete it as long as it is no duplicate (a quick [google](https://www.google.com/?q="igraph"+"Warning+message%3A+In+if+(axes)+{+%3A+the+condition+has+length+>+1+and+only+the+first+element+will+be+used") did not show any duplicate). Maybe other users will find it helpful, too, in connection with `igraph`.

Comment: @lukeA so better move your comment to the status of an answer, isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd argument of `plot.igraph` is `axes`. You were effectively giving it a matrix, where it wants a logical TRUE/FALSE value. So it used the first value of the matrix, coerced it to a boolean value and threw out a warning.

After adding the `layout` argument it will work as expected:

```
plot(rG, layout=layout_on_grid(rG, dim=2))
```